# React + TS, how to pass props from components A & B to components C, when props are slightly different and describe C props type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

[image]

I got two components: `Red` and `Blue` in React, I need to pass props to `Yellow` component, but the passed objects are slightly different `(const A & const B)`. If I describe `props.passed` type in `Yellow` as a union type `TypeA | TypeB` it will be fine unless I try to access `props.passed.A.c` property, which doesn't exist on `TypeB`.

**Is there a way to describe `Yellow` component's `prop.passed` type so as to avoid the error shown at the bottom of the picture ?**

*Note: I'm not allowed to divide `const A`'s properties and pass them separately from `props.passed`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to check if `passed` contains `c`:

```
type TypeA = {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: object
}
type TypeB = {
    a: string
    b: string
}

const f = (passed: TypeA | TypeB) => {
    console.log(passed.a)
    if ('c' in passed) {
        console.log(passed.c)
    }
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8CwAoKuoEMAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHNs8oAjYsquhvAY2IHsmAVhC7BsAX2yhIseACEU6TriKkKNejjwtV7DRKzYuvamSgAzBQAow+EiQgATYnEhIAPjMiyAlCgB8ipq4Ria8ADYQAHRhvLTWtvYOkfjeSlCUFpYA5FxZ6dRQNnaOvphBjFAhJOFRMXFFiZFcqeX6YkA)